# Why don't OTPs have letters?

Tags: one-time-password

Is there a reason why OTPs (one-time passwords) are only made up of numbers? I've seen OTPs of varying lengths but all of them are only made up of numbers. Why are they not alphanumeric?

Answer (score 1):

1. Some systems do use alpha one time password. S/Key or the less old OpieKey are example of them
2. For OTP systems using hardware calculators, the price of the hardware matters, and digital displays able to display only digits are cheaper than ones able to display letters
3. The OTP is generally computed as a mere number (ie a sequence of bits). It can then be represented as a decimal integer (only digits), an hexa integer (0-9 + A-F), encoded in base64 (alphanumeric ASCII), or in a any other encoding. The already cited S/Key used a number of 4 letter words.

Comment: Personally, if I have to enter an OTP on my phone, I also enjoy having an on-screen keyboard with 10 large keys rather than 37 small ones.